# C program has memory leak

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have made a function in C called `strremovestr` to remove substring from string, but there's a memory leak.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char* strremovestr(const char* data,const char* what){
    const int ws = strlen(what);
    const int ds = strlen(data);
    size_t currsize = ds;
    char* newdata=(char*)malloc(currsize+1);
    strcpy(newdata, data);
    newdata[currsize] = '\0';
    const char* hehe = NULL;
    while((hehe=strstr(newdata, what))){
        size_t detent = hehe - newdata;
        memmove(newdata+detent, ewdata + detent + ws,currsize - detent - ws+ 1);
        currsize-=ws;
    }
    newdata=realloc(newdata,currsize + 1);
    newdata[currsize] = '\0';
    return newdata;
}
int main(){
    printf("%s\n",strremovestr("hello", "e"));
    return 0;
}
```

Now this is reproducible example, you can run with valgrind to confirm that it has memory leak.
I had to add spacing between things in this code to make it more easier to read :)

Where's the memory leak here? Thanks for reading.

Comment: malloc create allocation and return reference to the newly created string?
Why aren't you modifying in place? I might be wrong I didn't look long, I want to know what it is.

Comment: https://valgrind.org/info/about.html

Comment: @TimothyH I wanted to left original data unmodified.

Comment: @Lime Stone You allocated an array dynamically but did not free the allocated memory in the program. Just write for example char *s = strremovestr("hello", "e"); printf("%s\n",s); free( s );

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yeah i realized just now...

Comment: In the sequence: `const int ds = strlen(data);` — `size_t currsize = ds;` — `char* newdata=(char*)malloc(currsize+1);` — `strcpy(newdata, data);` — `newdata[currsize] = '\0';` — the final assignment is redundant; `strcpy()` already wrote a null byte there.

Comment: You don't show how you're determining that this code is leaking memory ([Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/)?).  However, the chances are this is what is allocating the leaked memory, but the code calling this is not freeing what was allocated and returned by this function, thus creating the leak.  In other words, the problem is not in the code you show but in the code you don't show.

Comment: Completely tangentially: the `realloc()` may not be beneficial unless the amount of data removed was considerable (say, more than 64 bytes, but the threshold is negotiable).  Otherwise, you are invoking the (fairly expensive) memory allocation system to release space that cannot easily be reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate the memory

```
char* newdata=(char*)malloc(currsize+1);
```

but you never free it.

```
int main()
{
    char *str;
    printf("%s\n",(str = strremovestr("hello", "e")));
    free(str);
}
```

also:

- `strlen` returns size_t not `int`
- do not cast the result of `malloc`
- store result of the `realloc` in temporary pointer. Otherwise if `realloc` fails, you will have another memory leak.
- check the result of memory allocation functions.
- `newdata[currsize] = '\0';` `strcpy` copies null terminating character too. It is not needed

Comment: you are right, i forgot about that. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The following allocation is never freed:

char* newdata=(char*)malloc(currsize+1);

You've got several choices here:

1. either you allocate the memory in the main and pass the pointer to your function that will work inside the malloc, and will reallocate it to the new size. (This way, you can't pass a constant string like "hello" because you can't realloc a static string).
2. or you return the allocated string, but it's the responsibility of the caller to free it after.